# how to implement a two colums listview which each colum is not align with the others

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

I want to implement a new widget,it's similar to listview or girdview,it has two colums,but in each row, the one of colums is not align with the other one.User can scroll the widget like listview,and i also need to consider the reuse of the view in widget,as the listview resolution.So please help figure out how to finish this widget or who has ever implement this kind of widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the StaggeredListView that is part of the AOSP experimental branch. Have to checked that out?

There is a library [here](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/) that I think will get you what you are after.

Comment: Thanks,I am so happy that you understand what I said.